# Strange NSScreen Coordinates

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

This is the constructor of my `NSWindow` subclass called `FullScreenWindow` :

```
- (id)initWithScreen:(NSScreen *)s {
NSRect contentRect = [s frame];
self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect
                        styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                          backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                            defer:NO
                           screen:s];
if (self) {
    [self setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary|
                                NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|
                                NSWindowCollectionBehaviorIgnoresCycle];
    [self setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
    [self setOpaque:NO];
    [self setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel-1];
}
return self;
```

}

I wanna add such an `NSWindow` to every display in `[NSScreen screens]` but when I connect a second display, the windows only display the right way if I set `origin.x` of `contentRect` to `-1440` for the first display (and `0` for the second one). When I get `origin.x` values of the frames of the `NSScreen` instances it returns `0` for the first display and `1440` for the second one. Why are these coordinates shifted?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built-in full-screen support of NSView?

Answer (score 11):

One of the [NSScreen screens] will have (0, 0) as origin.
Now imagine 2 axes: Y goes up from (0, 0) and X goes to the right.
All other screens will have coordinates with this coordinate system and screen.frame.origin will represent bottom left corner.

[image]

I could not find this in the documentation, so I found this experimenting with displays arrangement.
I had this picture with two monitors: main one 1366x768, secondary 1680x1050, aligned to the top.
I tried also different arrangements, moving #1 around #0, and my hypothesis was always correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this!

Comment: The main monitor is the one that'll have the (0,0) origin